# Is there a way to to use Salesforce DX for continuous integration with TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, salesforce, teamcity, continuous-deployment, setup-deployment

I have seen lot of sources for using Salesforce DX for continuous integration with Jenkins but nothing with TeamCity. Our company is using TeamCity for build management for other web service teams. I'm trying to find a source if we can do continuous integration with TeamCity. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I am also interested to understand support of using Salesforce DX and TeamCity.  Seems there is information on using Jenkins and other CI platforms but not TeamCity.  So I too am interested in the answer to this post.  Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking for help on setting up teamcity for Salesforce DX, any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks